# Send a fax from a PC to a Brother MFC-240C All-in-one

Tags: windows, fax, all-in-one

Here is the situation:
There is a Brother MFC-240C All-in-one printer/fax/scanner connected via usb to the computer. Is there any way I could send a fax that I had typed up on the PC directly to the fax (without printing it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by downloading the **Brother MFC-240C driver and software** package. It contained a program that sets up a virtual printer, which if printed to, starts up a fax program that then sends the data to the printer and tells it that it is a fax.
Visit [this page](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/dlf/download_top.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc240c_all), then
 * select your OS
 * download the "Full driver and Software Package"
 * Install it
 * Then print to the printer named something like "Fax" or "Windows Fax".